# How do I mock an invokable in a ZF2 unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm trying to run a unit test on a controller that has a view that uses a view helper.  My invokable is set up in my helper config as so:

```
<?php
return [
    'invokables' => [
        'viewHelper' => 'Theme\View\Helper\ViewHelper',
    ],
];
```

In my unit test, I have a number of services mocked in the setUp().

```
<?php

namespace Blargle\Controller;

class ActivityControllerTest extends AbstractZendHttpControllerTestCase
{
    /**
     * Someone set up us the bomb.
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $mockActivityRepository = $this->getMock('Domain\Repository\Blargle\ActivityRepositoryInterface');
        $this->serviceManager->setService('Blargle\ActivityRepository', $mockActivityRepository);
    }

    /**
     * Test Add Action
     */
    public function testAddAction()
    {
        $this->createIdentity(); //Sets up the logged in user.

        $this->dispatch('/blargle/activity/add/1');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);

        $this->assertModuleName('blargle');
        $this->assertControllerName('Blargle\Controller\Activity');
        $this->assertControllerClass('ActivityController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('blargle/activity');

        $mvcEvent = $this->getApplication()->getMvcEvent();
        $viewModel = $mvcEvent->getResult();

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Zend\View\Model\ViewModel', $viewModel);
        $this->assertEquals($viewModel->getTemplate(), 'blargle/activity/add');
    }
}
```

So, I now need to mock the invokable that gets loaded by the view, but the service manager that the view relies on is tied to the view.  I've tried:

```
$mockHelper = $this->getMock('Theme\View\Helper\ViewHelper');
$this->serviceManager->setService('viewHelper', $mockHelper);
```

This is fruitless since this now lives in the controller service manager, while a peer one seems to be spawned with the view.  The view unfortunately creates a new instance of the service before it goes out and looks at its peers for an instance.

So, with that, any ideas on how to effectively mock this?

Comment: You could mock a service manager to return a mock service, and call setServiceManager($your_mock_service_manager) on your object?

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to mock the helper before dispatching your request :)

```
public function testMethod()
{
    /**
      * mock of your invokable class
      */
    $mock = ...;

    $sm = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
    $sm->setAllowOverride(true);
    $sm->setService('viewHelper', $mock);
    $sm->setAllowOverride(false);

    // your invokable is now mocked
}
```